# Linking of homePage view to other views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to link my home page view to other views but it's not working
I also tried to take only a single view but it still not working
I also don't know how to connect multiple views into a single URL

app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from homePage.forms import SignInForm,DropUsaMessage
# Create your views here.
def homePage(request):
    sign_in_detail=SignIn
    message_detail=DropUsaMessage
    return render(request, "index.html",{"form":sign_in_detail,"forms":message_detail})

def SignIn(request):
    sign_in_detail=SignInForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sign_in_detail = SignInForm(request.POST)
        if sign_in_detail.is_valid():
            return render(request, "index2.html",{"form":sign_in_detail})
    else:
        sign_in_detail = SignInForm()
        # "form":sign_in_detail
    return render(request, "index.html",{})

def Contact(request):
    message_detail=DropUsaMessage()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message_detail = DropUsaMessage(request.POST)
        if message_detail.is_valid():
            return homePage(request)
    else:
        message_detail = DropUsaMessage()
        # "forms":message_detail
    return render(request, "index.html",{"forms":message_detail})
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
        path('', views.homePage),
]
```

app/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

class SignInForm(forms.Form):
    email=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": 'form-control',"placeholder":'Enter E-mail',"id": 'exampleInputEmail1'}))
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Enter Password',"id":'exampleInputPassword1'}))

class DropUsaMessage(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Your Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": 'form-control',"placeholder":'Your E-mail',"id": 'exampleInputEmail1'}))
    phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Your Phone Number'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Type Your Message',"style":'width:100%; height: 150px'}))
```

index.html

```
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="{% static 'img/sampleImage.jpg' %}" width="100%" height="100%" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form }}
              <div class="form-check">
                  <span class="fpswd">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="SignIn">Submit</button>
            </form>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
<div class="container contact-form">
              <form  method="post">
                      <h3>Drop Us a Message</h3>
                              {% csrf_token %}
                              {{ forms }}<br><br>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="submit" name="SendMessage" class="btnContact" value="Send Message" />
                              </div>



              </form>
      </div>
```

the signin field is not showing up. there is a long address is showing in django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give names to your URL patterns like below:

```
urlpatterns=[
        path('', views.homePage, name='home'),
]
```

Then in your templates you can use Jinja to reference these names like.

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

You can get a little help from DjangoProject site tutorial with the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/).

**UPDATE:**

You need to create a Navbar (Navigation bar). You can then call all your pages with URLS in your home page. Like

```
Home | Services | Portfolio
```

You need to create urlpatterns with name for each page and you can then use it like.

```
<ul><li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li> 
<ul><li><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Services</a></li>
<ul><li><a href="{% url 'portfolio' %}">Portfolio</a></li>.
```

So then all the pages will link up to your home page and you can navigate.

For that you need to create 3 respective views like below in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
        path('', views.homePage, name='home'),
        path('services/', views.servicePage, name='services'),
        path('portfolio/', views.portfolioPage, name='portfolio'),
]
```

Comment: but the problem is still the same I want all 3 views in a single page(homePage). if I use urlpatterns then I have to write different-different names in ' ' . and after that, I have to reload the page acc to it like 127.0.0.1:8000/, 127.0.0.1:8000/message and 127.0.0.1:8000/signin

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you out. See under "UPDATE" section in my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

You *can not* have multiple views on a single URL. One URL maps to a single view.

Comment: then how can I make a webpage which is having multiple views

Comment: I just said: you can't. Why do you want to? One view equals one page.

Comment: @TanmayKumar you've been explained with the logic pretty well by MudassarHashmi. You can call your views or pages as ref on a single page as per your original question. You should make one view equals to one page but still you can call attributes or functions from different views/models in a single view. That's why you need to practice official tutorial as suggested above.